# Not loading all page source PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get a website source with a curl call but some data is missing and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
If i make a call to the url in browser in the page source will apear `<!-- request captchas: blabla -->`..
but after I call in php it will bring in the page source: `"<!-- request captchas: null -->"`
My code:

```
$url='http://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/informatii_publice/informatii_agenti_economici/registrul_inactivi_reactivati/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0)         Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=0001R8jflCwCXeYrmbF45vBxtS-:3KMDRVUOUV");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $html;
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the problem, I don't understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add  `curl_init()`.

Do like this..

```
<?php
$url='http://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/informatii_publice/informatii_agenti_economici/registrul_inactivi_reactivati/';
$ch = curl_init(); //<-------------- Add this here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0)         Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=0001R8jflCwCXeYrmbF45vBxtS-:3KMDRVUOUV");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=0001R8jflCwCXeYrmbF45vBxtS-:3KMDRVUOUV");
```